# SQL Find duplicate rows without a column with value

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to

```
transactionid | ordernumber
aaaa            1
aaaa            NULL
bbbb            2
bbbb            NULL
cccc            NULL
```

I need to find the rows in the database where the transaction ID does not have an order number associated with it. So for this example, the query should only return cccc and not aaaa or bbbb since there is an order number associated with those transactions.

I've tried many things but have not had any luck. I'm sure it's pretty simple and I'm just making it overly complicated. Obviously if I do a query where ordernumber is NULL I'll still receive transactions that could possibly have ordernumbers associated with them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group by the `transactionid` and sum up all `ordernumber` that are not `null`. That sum must be `0`

```
select transactionid 
from your_table
group by transactionid 
having sum(case when ordernumber is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: I didnt even think of that! Thank you so much!